# 3.5" LCD driver conflicts with UART

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero-w, uart, pigpio, lcd

I'm using RPi Zero W with 3.5" LCD driver ( [here](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show) ). Everything works well except the UART. Linux console is disabled and UART is enabled. When video output is on HDMI port, I can send and receive bytes ( a loop back test program) on pin 8 & 10 ( GPIO 14 & 15) but when I switch to LCD output, it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**

OS version: Raspbian Buster, updated with the latest packages.

LCD connects to the board by SPI protocol.

I use LCD35-show script.

Comment: I would pop a few more details in your question such as the OS version, how the Pi and LCD connect, the model of the LCD and the command you are running to change display type (the driver supports many) - from these folk maybe able to help you a bit more without the question being closed down.

Comment: @Andyroo I just updated the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! In case anyone had the same problem, the goodtft driver adds `console=ttyAMA0,115200` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file. Just remove it and you are done!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.